# File is empty with shared volume

Tags: docker

I have a little problem with the docker.
I'm trying to use a volume share with my computer. I can see the files on my computer, but they are empty from my container.

I tried to create a file in the /root of my container (outside the shared volume) and I can see the file without any problem.
If I do `echo test > test.txt` (in my shared volume), the file content is empty.

I execute this command :

```
docker run -v "D:\My App:/home/app" -it MyImage /bin/bash
```

In the /home/app folder, I can see the files on my computer. But if I do:

```
cat /home/app/test.txt
```

It tells me there's nothing in the file. While there is a text (the file exists)

If I create a file from my container, in the shared volume, I find it on my computer (and it is not empty).
If I create a file from my computer, I find it in the container, but it is empty when I try to display it.

Currently, when I do a cat `test.txt`, it doesn't display anything.
This should display `this is a test`

Comment: Are you creating the file/s or writing contents to the file/s BEFORE or AFTER running the container?

Comment: Before running the container. I use docker run for run the container and I execute the command in the shell (Bash)

Comment: What about vice versa, i.e. if you run `echo foo > /home/app/another_test.txt` in the container and then check the file content from your host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Do check first your Docker for Windows settings:

[image: Shared Drive]

If your D:\ drive is *not* shared, you won't see much in your container.

[`docker/for-win` issue 25](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/25) points out multiple possible issues:

If you are using Docker Toolbox:

> In my case Docker Toolbox created a VM named default in Virtualbox and I added the Shared Folder in the VM; `Virtualbox -> default (VM) -> Settings -> Shared Folders -> Add`:
>
> Then you can specify the paths in both your machine and the mapped path in the VM, like:
>
> - The 1st field is the path in your machine, like D:\my\app
> - The 2nd is the path in the VM, like /my-vm/app
> - Choose to Mount Automatically

Another:

> One of the issues I had when learning, was to try and mount a volume in my container, but then have a folder that conflicted.
>   For example, I'd make my workingdir `/foo/bar`, then try to use a volume for `/foo/bar/private` as well, BUT already have a folder called private in my initial mount.
>   I would see no error, but I'd see the first folder and not my 2nd volume

Or:

[`docker/for-win` issue 2151](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2151): "**Volumes mounted from a Linux WSL instance don't resolve in container**".
It refers to "[how to use Docker with WSL](http://%20https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)".

> The last thing we need to do is set things up so that volume mounts work. This tripped me up for a while because check this out…
>
> When using WSL, Docker for Windows expects you to supply your volume paths in a format that matches this: `/c/Users/nick/dev/myapp`.
>
> But, WSL doesn’t work like that. Instead, it uses the `/mnt/c/Users/nick/dev/myapp` format.
>   Honestly I think Docker should change their path to use `/mnt/c` because it’s more clear on what’s going on, but that’s a discussion for another time.